# Discord.js v12.2.0 | Add role based on reaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a bot with an automatic role system using reactions.
Here's a shortened version of my current relevant code:

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  if(!user || user.bot || !reaction.message.channel.guild) {
    return;
  }
  const msg = reaction.message;
  const role = msg.channel.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Verified");
  // I would like to add the role to the user here.
});
```

I just want to know how to add a role to a user with the `user` object.
I have tried `reaction.message.channel.guild.member(user).addRole(role);`, but I think that's deprecated for v12.2.0, as it just generates an error `...).addRole() is not a function`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 `addRole()` has been replaced with `roles.add()` so it is indeed not a function.

```js
reaction.message.guild.member(user).roles.add(role);
```